# COUNT(*) keeps returning a zero (0)

Tags: php, mysqli

This code:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{

    //Count function
    $count_likes=$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES FROM `comment_likes` WHERE comment_id_fk='".$row["comment_id"]."'");

    if($count_likes->num_rows > 0){
        echo $row["comment_id"];
        $row_array=$count_likes->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $row_array['TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES'] = ' ';
    }
    //End count function

    echo '<div class="media" id="item_'.$row["comment_id"].'">';
    echo '<p class="pull-right"><small>'. time_elapsed_string($row['date']) . '</small></p>';
    echo '<div class="media-left">';
    echo '<img src="images/avatar.png" height="35" width="35">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="media-body">';
    echo '<a href="#">Bo Broberg</a> ';
    echo convert_clickable_links($row["content"]);
    echo '<p><small><a href="">' . $row_array['TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES']. ' Like</a> - <a href="">Report</a> - <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["comment_id"].'">Delete</a></small></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Gives me this output

> Bo Broberg Jomen visst #hehe #ras2015 1 Like - Report - Delete
>
> 10 hours ago  Bo Broberg Awesome 0 Like - Report - Delete

And as you can see, in the second post, neither Bo Broberg or anyone els has pressed the like button, but it shows a 0.

How do i remove that zero??

If there is no likes, don't show the 0, only show the amount of likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a workaround, but it did it for me anyhow

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 if($result->num_rows === 0)
 {
    $how_many='';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always showing a zero because `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` will always return > 0 rows.

Given that, you can fix the ternary example below with:

```
echo '<p><small><a href="">' 
    . ((int)$row_array['TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES'] > 0)  
        ? what you want to happen with likes
        : what you don't if there aren't any
    . (the rest)
```

Comment: ^^ was adding that bit when you commented ;)

Comment: i tried `echo '<p><small><a href="">' . ((int)$row_array['TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES'] > 0)  ? ' likes</a>' :  'no likes</a>' . '- <a href="">Report</a> - <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["comment_id"].'">Delete</a></small></p>';` But still no luck.

Comment: If the ternary won't work, just use an if statement to check that count() result. There's no need to over complicate it for the sake of feeling clever (it runs equally as fast both ways).

Comment: i appreciate your help! But I'm having troubles with the ternary. My bad, sorry about that. Regarding the if statement. How do i remove the 0

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with concatenating strings in that fashion, but either way, no worries! Helping is fun.

Answer (score -1):

shorthand ternary operator (look it up for more info)

```
echo '<p><small><a href="">' . $row_array['TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES'] ?: "". ' Like</a> - <a href="">Report</a> - <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["comment_id"].'">Delete</a></small></p>';
```